# Automating Internet Explorer using C/C++

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, automation

I want to write a small utility which can automate internet explorer `using C++ (No MFC)`. 
Some of the actions which i want to automate are :-
1. Opening a url
2. Clicking on a hyperlink in the browser instance
3. Setting the value of text boxes
4. Checking checkboxes, drop down menus etc.

I am an absolute beginner, and have no experience with `COM`, however i am currently in the process of learning. 
Can anyone guide me, like suggesting the resources and a breif outline of what i need to do to automate.
I will really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Ashish.

Comment: If you're just learning create a C# winform app, drop in a WebBrowser control and hey presto!

Comment: Thanks @JeremyThompson but i cannot use C#, i want to use C++ and also learn a bit on COM, i have ordered INSIDE COM, waiting for it to get shipped. As of now COM is all confusing.

Comment: Component Object Model (COM) is really old now. With WinRT and the next visual studio 'vNext', MetroApps & etc just around the corner I'd recommend you opt for more up-to-date technology. The other suggestion is to use a Unit Test recorder - like Selenium for FireFox - but one targeted at IE, cheers

Comment: @JeremyThompson COM isn't going anywhere. It's an integral part of Windows and a lot of other Microsoft technologies.

Comment: I also suggest the book "Essential COM" by Don Box.  It shows you why COM came into being by describing the problems with the C++ binary model and how that is not portable across misc. C++ compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler COM support.

Generally it works like this:

```
#import "c:\path\to\typelib.tlb"

#import "c:\path\to\library.dll"

#import "c:\path\to\program.exe"
```

This then makes it very easy to use Internet Explorer or any other COM object from C++.

See here for documentation:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h31ekh7e.aspx

Comment: Hi @Ben I have come across IWebBrowser2 interface, i can use this to open an IE window, but how do i perform actions like clicking on Hyperlinks and filling text boxes? Any ideas?

Comment: From IWebBrowser2 you need to obtain the Document object using `get_Document`. From there you can control the document using the same DOM API as JavaScript running in the browser.

Comment: Can you point me to a resource or an example which controls the document using the DOM API. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It became magically clear while i was having a shower, Lol my own eureka moment. I am now able to click on hyperlinks. Thanks. Will try to post the code, once it is in good shape.

Comment: @AshishKumarShah do you have any success trying to manipulate forms  ?

Comment: @motto, I have had success manipulating forms using this method.

Comment: Sorry i don't have an example to hand. However it is pretty much a straight translation of the equivalent JavaScript or VB.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy Thompson suggested the basic answer: use a WebBrowser control. That's far easier in C#, because it includes quite some of the boilerplate code you need. Even MFC contains some of that. Without that, you'll need to implement a proper ActiveX container. For someone not knowing COM at all, this is highly non-trivial. ActiveX is an advanced COM technique. There's a bit of sample code [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/196339/en-us)

Once you've hosted it, things become fairly trivial in comparison. Opening a URL is just a single call: `IWebBrowser2::Navigate(URL, flags...)`

Comment: I am able to perform a navigate, i need help in performing other actions like clicking on a link and filling text boxes etc.